# comments value is working for first post ONLY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to be able to leave a comment on a post, for that I've retrieved all the posts.

I've a button called **Comment** which when I click I want to fetch current comment `body`, `post_id` and `user_id` so that to save them in the `comments` table.

here is the  **Problem**:
when I click on **Comment** for **first** post, the comment `body` , `post_id`, and `user_id` are being fetched perfectly fine and I've alerted them before **ajax** request,they are ok for first post, but for remaining `posts` when I click on **Comment** button, I get `id` of the **first** post and nothing for comment `body`, even when I click on **Comment** button for other than first post, it returns the `id` of first post.

I'm using Laravel, here is my code:

**Controller**

```
Route::post('comment/{post_id}',[

'uses' => 'CommentController@storeComments',
]);
```

**`storeComments` Function**

```
 public function storeComments(Request $request,Comment $body,$post_id){

   if(!$request->ajax()){
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id;
    $comment->body = Input::get('body');

    $comment->save();
     $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
    );
     return Response::json($response);
     return 'yes';
   }else{
    return 'no';
    }
 }
```

Here is my **form**.
I've used `foreach` loop to get all the post and there inside that loop I've used `textarea` for the comment in the following form.

```
@foreach


 <form action="{{ url('comment',$post->p_id)  }}" method="POST"  > 
   @csrf
    <textarea 
    name="body"


     placeholder="Write A Suggestion" 
     data-autosize-input='{ "space": 100 }' 
     rows="50" cols="100"
     name="comment"  
      class="form-control comment body">

     </textarea> 
        <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">


        <!-- user Id of the logged In one -->

            <input type="text" class="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" name="user_id">

            <!-- post id  -->

            <input type="text" class="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{$post->p_id}}">



        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger formcomment" value = 'Comment' style="margin:10px;">Comment</button> 
    </form>


@endforeach
```

Here is **Ajax Request**

```
<!--  actuall here control does not comes okay -->
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.formcomment').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // these are id's
    var body = $('.body').val();
    var post_id = parseInt($('.post_id').val());
    var user_id = parseInt($('.user_id').val());

    alert(body);
    alert('this is post'+post_id);
    alert('This is user id'+user_id);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/comment',
        data: {body:body, post_id:post_id, user_id:user_id},
        success: function(msg) {
            $("body").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
        }
    });
});


});
```

**Note:**

I've searched for this problem, some suggestion were to change the `id` to `class` because in Jquery `id's` should be unique for different fields.

As the form is inside `@foreach` loop and the fields are different for each post.

Hope this make some sense, I really tried my best to make this simple.

I'm new to laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single one of your posts has the 3 elements .body, .post_id and .user_id. When you click your button you select the input fields based on this class. But since you have multiple elements of that class you always select just the first which leads to your error. You need to select the classes from the form in which you clicked the link :

change

```
// these are id's
var body = $('.body').val();
var post_id = parseInt($('.post_id').val());
var user_id = parseInt($('.user_id').val());
```

to

```
var form = $(this).closest('form);
// these are id's
var body = form.find('.body').val();
var post_id = parseInt(form.find('.post_id').val());
var user_id = parseInt(form.find('.user_id').val());
```

This should give you the elements of the right form

Comment: that's amazing, really helpful

Comment: well, I'm fetching those values correctly but they are not being sent to the `url` I've used i.e comment.
when I click on Comment button, in console it says `page not found`.

Can you've a look at the `route` at the top and the `url` in ajax request, they are okay ? @Lapskaus

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but the route you posted seems to expect an id within the url, you just call it with /comment in your ajax request though add the post_id to your url : url: '/comment' + post_id,

Comment: Yeah, I tried that by passing the `post_id` as parameter but that is not working !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Route::post('comment/{post_id}',[

'uses' => 'CommentController@storeComments',
]);
storeComments Function

 public function storeComments(Request $request,$post_id){

   if(!$request->ajax()){
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id;
    $comment->body = $request->get('body');

    $comment->save();
     $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
    );
     return Response::json($response);
     return 'yes';
   }else{
    return 'no';
    }
 }
Here is my form. I've used foreach loop to get all the post and there inside that loop I've used textarea for the comment in the following form.

@foreach


 <form  method="POST"  > 
   @csrf
    <textarea 
    name="body" id="body" 


     placeholder="Write A Suggestion" 
     data-autosize-input='{ "space": 100 }' 
     rows="50" cols="100"
     name="comment"  
      class="form-control comment body">

     </textarea> 
        <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">


        <!-- user Id of the logged In one -->

            <input type="text" class="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" name="user_id">

            <!-- post id  -->

            <input type="text" class="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{$post->p_id}}">



        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger formcomment" value = 'Comment' style="margin:10px;">Comment</button> 
    </form>


@endforeach
Here is Ajax Request

<!--  actuall here control does not comes okay -->
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.formcomment').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // these are id's
    var body = $('#body').val();
    var post_id = parseInt($('#post_id').val());
    var user_id = parseInt($('#user_id').val());

    alert(body);
    alert('this is post'+post_id);
    alert('This is user id'+user_id);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/comment/{{$post->p_id}}",
        data: {body:body, post_id:post_id, user_id:user_id},
        success: function(msg) {
            $("body").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
        }
    });
});


});
```